# SharePoint 2010 - Read list item from Central Adminstrator list

Tags: central-administration, splistitem

I have created list (say List1) on Central Administration Site. I would like to read the title value from that list programmatically. How can I do it? I don't want to hard code the URL of central administration site.

Also, in my code I have SPWebApplication object of Central Admin .Let me know if I can use it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your web application object in the function like below :

```
private string GetListTitle(SPWebApplication webApp)
    {
        //To ensure if your web application object hosts central admin
        if (webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication)
        {
            SPList list = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["List1"];
            return list.Title;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```